In material nodes, can I use Texture Coordinate and vector math instead of drivers to copy rotation from an object?
I have a material that uses a rotation that I get with drivers from an object. This method works but I wonder if I can avoid drivers, by using some combination of the Texture Coordinate node that allows you to pick an object. The object coordinates output by this node seem like a starting point, if I could somehow extract a rotation vector and convert it to a Euler rotation.
Is this possible or am I stuck with drivers? I did see a method that uses an empty parented to a light or another empty, is that a better method for calculating the light?

Here is what is inside the group, to calculate the light in simple way:


I don't think this is possible, because you can only access sample position relative to other object's position. So per sample this is just one position. You have more options if you need to calculate the rotation of self, but then you don't need to calculate anything as you can just read rotation_euler from "Attribute" node. So the alternative to drivers could be geonodes and storing the rotation on a face attribute for example.

Dang that's exactly what I did, a GN mod with an object picked. Thanks for the confirmation!

You can probably use the "Vector Transform" node to change the Z vector (or the normal) from world to object (or object to world).
Example: in your second picture, replace the "Vector Rotate" with a "Vector Transform" (I think it should be object to world)

The problem is, he wants to access another object's transformation, not self ("Attribute" node would work then) or world properties.
